# How to display name from custom attribute in product view page

Tags: magento2, name

Currently product name (title) is displayed from attribute `name`.

How to display product name (title) from custom attribute `second_name` on product view page?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**`Setp 1 :-`** Go to or override **`app/design/frontend/Your_CompanyName/Your_ThemeName/Magento_catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`** and add this code.

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.demo" template="product/view/demo.phtml" after="page.main.title">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getProductName</argument>
        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">product_name</argument>
        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">product_name</argument>
        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">ProductName</argument>
        <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="product_name"</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Above code attribute name change as per your attribute name. Custom Attribute Just i have shown after main product title.

**`Step 2 :-`** Create New file like **`app/design/frontend/YOUR_VENDOR/YOUR_THEME/Magento_catalog/templates/product/view/demo.phtml`**. Add below code

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$_code = $block->getAtCode();
$_className = $block->getCssClass();
$_attributeLabel = $block->getAtLabel();
$_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
$_attributeAddAttribute = $block->getAddAttribute();
if ($_attributeLabel && $_attributeLabel == 'default') {
$_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontendLabel();
}
$_attributeValue =$_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
?>
<?php if ($_attributeValue): ?>
<div>
    <div class="value" <?php echo $_attributeAddAttribute;?>><?php echo $_attributeValue; ?></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

After you run below one command like:-

**`- php bin/magento c:f`**

**`Output :-`**

[image]

Other thing if you want to show listing page. Follow below setps

**`Setp 1 :-`** Go to your custom attribute and To Display, the new attribute in List Page, set the value “YES” to **`“Used in Product Listing”`** under storefront Properties while creating the attribute.

**`Setp 2 :-`** To display the attribute value in product list page, add the below code in **`app/design/frontend/YOUR_VENDOR/YOUR_THEME/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`**. Add below code.

**`<?php echo$_item->getDemoLink(); ?>`**

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: Hell Mohit, thanks for reply. This not working for me. Can you please check my code? I need to overite standard title and display this from attribute second_name https://prnt.sc/22tgxs0

Comment: and then I add this code and custom to second_name https://prnt.sc/22th5uv and add demo.phtml to this path and after c:f no result

Comment: In your demo.phtml file first lie add `echo "Hello"; die();` Your demo.phtml file call or not?